# Wake up laptop on AC while UEFI (BIOS) does not have that option

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, sleep, power-management

Been trying to setup my external monitor + laptop to act as a desktop (both to turn on with AC). Almost there - followed this thread which was massively useful, thanks all.
[Turn on Windows 10 laptop without opening it if external monitor is attached?](https://superuser.com/questions/1261576/turn-on-windows-10-laptop-without-opening-it-if-external-monitor-is-attached/1537103#1537103)

The issue:
1) I would love to use 'Wake up on AC' BIOS settings as this is ideal indeed (plug in electricity -> both monitor and laptop switched on). However, my UEFI does not support this :-(. I scanned everywhere but my UEFI settings are simply too barebone. 4 yr old Lenovo laptop here. Always on USB enabled in UEFI.

2) As an acceptable alternative, I enabled wake up by keyboard in Win 10. This is good. Until a certain point, I reckon 3 hr after being in sleep mode, the laptop goes into 'deeper sleep' and then keyboard would not wake it up by any means.

What solutions would you recommend please? Think I could tackle 2) by disabling deep sleep in my Win power plan. But this is undesired, I do want the laptop to go into high energy saving mode e.g. overnight. I would ideally fine tune 1). I know my old BIOS on this laptop could do it... but flashing up BIOS because of such a small thing sounds like a risky overkill to me.

Big thanks to you all.