# Turn on Windows 10 laptop, with lid closed using keyboard attached to KVM switch

Tags: laptop, sleep, wake-up

I've got a laptop that I occasionally take to work, but mostly I just want to keep tucked away at the side. What I would like to be able to do, is turn it on without pushing the power button, meaning I can leave the lid closed.

I found this very helpful answer, however my situation is slightly different and when going to "Device Manager" to select "Allow device to wake computer" the option is not available.
[Turn on Windows 10 laptop without opening it if external monitor is attached?](https://superuser.com/questions/1261576/turn-on-windows-10-laptop-without-opening-it-if-external-monitor-is-attached#)

My setup, currently consists of a desktop and laptop, with two monitors. Both monitors are connected directly to the two devices (using the monitors settings to select which device is displayed). My keyboard and mouse however are connected via a KVM switch, with the KVM switch connecting to the two devices.

I suspect because of this, the laptop isn't allowing me to wake it using the KB/Mouse.

Can anyone recommend a solution? Are there good apps to wake via phone or other methods for waking a laptop might be worth looking into?

The laptop is a lenovo E15. KVM is a cheap one from ebay. Keyboard is a Filco Majestouch Convertible 2.

Thank you for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone still looking for a solution, you will need a KVM with DDM for this set up to work. It's not going to be a computer settings problem, unless you want to mess around with your laptop's registry. With DDM (Dynamic Device Mapping) Technology, the communication between shared peripherals and all connected systems are maintained 100% of the time, even as a user switches between the KVM ports.